# BBM bar export fail on heavy APK

Tags: apk, blackberry-10

I've already export BBM bar application without problem meanwhile I'm trying to export my application of around 10Mo size and got an error .Can someone help me ? Is there something to configure or is it a bug ?

Thanks in advance for your help :Clap:

StackTrace :

Click the "Details" button to see details
Packaging failed:-1

```
C:\eclipse>set LIB=C:\eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ajde_1.5.2.201302260701\blackberry.tools.SDK\bin\\..\lib

C:\eclipse>java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx512M -cp "C:\eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ajde_1.5.2.201302260701\blackberry.tools.SDK\bin\\..\lib\BARPackager.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ajde_1.5.2.201302260701\blackberry.tools.SDK\bin\\..\lib\Apk2Bar.jar" net.rim.tools.apk2bar.Apk2Bar C:\workspace-sts\MyProject\bin\MyProject.apk C:\android-sdks\ -t "C:\workspace-sts\MyProject\dist\Android 4.2.2"
Apk2Bar version 1.5.2
Research In Motion Ltd ? 2012 All rights reserved.
[MyProject.apk]:smileysad:AndroidManifest.xml) targetSdkVersion: 17 is higher than 10:impact=1
[MyProject.apk]:Resizing icon app_icon.png 512x512 -> 114x114
[ERROR] Exception during packaging: Unknown image type 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown image type 0
at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(Unknown Source)
at net.rim.tools.apk2bar.Apk2Bar.resize(Apk2Bar.java:523)
at net.rim.tools.apk2bar.Apk2Bar.packageBar(Apk2Bar.java:418)
at net.rim.tools.apk2bar.Apk2Bar.main(Apk2Bar.java:312)
Summary: Total Apk files # 1 succeeded: 0 skipped: 0 failed: 1
Summary: [5]=1; [4]=0; [3]=0; [2]=0; [1]=1;
Impact Legend: [5]=Severe; [4]=High /context; [3]=Medium /context; [2]=Medium-low /context; [1]=Minor;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like, from what you have there is a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument.
From looking at your error message there it should be a problem with one of your images, and i don't think it because the program re-sized the icon. If there's more image types in your program check them out, you might need a try and catch statement.

Also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html
just shows the exception, i just used google to find it.

Comment: The IllegalArgumentException is being thrown by apk2bar so the OP will have no way of debugging it further

Comment: I think the problem may come form the BBM command Apk2Bar which can't resize the picture ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the icon resize operation is failing. Try resizing your icon to 114x114 then apk2bar won't need to resize it.